# Анимация ожидания

Tags: android

Нужно заблокировать экран и вывести картинку ожидания, пока не выполнится некое действие

Comment: а если пользователь нажмет кнопку home? или это также нужно заблокировать?

Похоже, что Вам нужен самый обычный сервис, который выполнит всю работу, а основная активити просто будет проверять работу сервиса и не давать что то делать.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от решаемой задачи можно воспользоваться Handler'ом, AsyncTask'ом или Loader'ом. Можно конечно и сервис создать, а потом принять из него результат, но для какой нибудь небольшой задачи, это сравнимо со стрельбой из пушки по воробьям.

Вот хорошие статьи на русском, по этим темам:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/143-urok-80-handler-nemnogo-teorii-nagljadnyj-primer-ispolzovanija.html

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/148-urok-85-esche-neskolko-sposobov-vypolnenija-koda-v-ui-potoke.html

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/274-urok-135-loader-loadermanager-asynctaskloader.html

И вот хорошая статья на английском с похожим к желаемому примером:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Я не знаю, какова задача решаемая на фоне, но в большинстве случаев, я думаю подойдет AsyncTask. Можно, в вашем случае, вывести блокирующий диалог, а по окончании выполнении фоновой задачи, убрать его. Можно просто пройтись по всей иерархии View и вызвать setEnabled(false), вот даже универсальный пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views. Еще можно поместить поверх всех View ProgressBar и сделать так, чтоб его было видно при помощи setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), а то что под ним - нет при помощи setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), а по окончании загрузки сделать наоборот. В общем способов много, в зависимости от того, что конкретно нужно.